# Does not GLES20 Have GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, precision

My question is simple. Why isn't there any `GL_HALF_FLOAT_OES` constant on Java side in GLES20.java class? However, "GLES2/gl2ext.h" on native side, has it... what happens if i specify value of this C constant on Java side manually? Do you think it is not valid and this is why they had not included it within GLES20.java class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float point textures are not a part of OpenGL ES 2.0 specs that's why they are not included in `gl2ext.h`. And please note that they are available only if GPU supports `GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float` extension so you should check presence of this extension first.

Basically, you won't find constants for a lot of vendor-specific stuff too. This doesn't mean these values are invalid and it is absolutely OK to define these constants in code (my code has a lot of such constants, to name a few - constants for DXT/PVRTC compression and Tegra's CSAA).

Comment: Ah. I see. Then in my java code, i can use these constants as long as the underlying hardware supports it. Thank you.